# How to replicate a field data for all of the existing orders in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, wordpress-admin

I have a field CIF in my Woocommerce, I have 1000 orders with this field complete. This field shows because I used a plugin. ID Field is billing_cifnif.

Now I need to change this plugin for other plugin and I need that old field to be duplicated in a new field ID billing_nif.

I need to fill these `1000 orders` with the new value.

I have this code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'replicate_billing_email', 100, 1);

function replicate_billing_email($order_id){
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id); 
    $billing_cifnif = $order->get_billing_cifnif(); 
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'billing_nif', $billing_cifnif);
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_nif', $billing_cifnif);
}
```

It only works for new orders, I need to use it for the old orders.

Thank you

Comment: Does `$billing_cifnif` variable return any value? Can you confirm that?

Comment: Hello!! Yes has a value

Answer (score 2):

> *"Only works for new orders, I need to use it for the old orders."*

If you want to update your existing orders, then run the following snippet **ONCE**. After it's done running, delete it from the `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'updating_orders_metadata');

function updating_orders_metadata()
{
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array('numberposts' => -1));

    if ($orders) 
    {
        foreach ($orders as $order) 
        {
            $billing_cifnif = $order->get_billing_cifnif();

            if ($billing_cifnif) 
            {
                update_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'billing_nif', $billing_cifnif);
                update_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_billing_nif', $billing_cifnif);
            }
        }
        echo "<div style='background-color: lightgreen; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;'>Done updating the orders! You may now delete the script from the functions.php file</div>";
    }
};
```

**NOTE:**

- In order for updates to happen you would need to refresh your website home page **ONCE**. After your website home page is done loading and you see the green notice, go back to the `functions.php` file and remove the script!

[image]

- I was not sure if you needed both `billing_nif` and `_billing_nif`, so I included both! Please feel free to exclude/delete any of them as you see fit!